# Fancybox Caption does not work with Hyperlink including ampersands

Tags: jquery, fancybox, photo-gallery

I am using the latest [Fancybox 1.3.4](http://fancybox.net/) and the latest jQuery 1.6.1 and I am also using Hyperlinks in the caption, which works, e.g.:

```
<a 
  href="pathtoimage.jpg" 
  title="Some text and a hyperlink: &lt;a href=&quot;http://www.someclient.com&quot;&gt;LINKTEXT&lt;/a&gt;">
    <img src="pathtoimage.jpg" alt="alt text of image" />
</a>
```

But **the following does not work** if the target URL contains more than one parameter:

```
title="Some text and a hyperlink: &lt;a  href=&quot;http://www.someclient.com?a=1&amp;b=2&quot;&gt;LINKTEXT&lt;/a&gt;">
```

How can I encode `?a=1&b=2` correctly so that [Fancybox](http://fancybox.net/) does not break?

**Thanks!**

Javascript error in Chrome console:

```
Uncaught Error: INVALID_STATE_ERR: DOM Exception 11
f.extend.cleanjquery-1.6.1.min.js:18
f.buildFragmentjquery-1.6.1.min.js:17
f.fn.extend.domManipjquery-1.6.1.min.js:17
f.fn.extend.appendjquery-1.6.1.min.js:17
f.fn.extend.htmljquery-1.6.1.min.js:17
Qjquery.fancybox-1.3.4.pack.js:27
I.v.onload
```

Comment: Have you tried using the latest version of Fancybox ? (1.3.4)

Comment: True, I'll check that and update my question based on the results... thanks!

Comment: I just verified that, it still does **NOT work**

Comment: Maybe try using the latest version of jQuery too, and leave simple ampersands with your parameters (i.e. don't encode `?a=1&b=2`)

Comment: see updated question, also with **jQuery 1.6.1**, it **does not work**. I'm very sure that fancybox is the issue. but nobody answers in the official google group...

Comment: without encoding it didn't work at all, the whole page rendering was broken (xhtml)

Comment: I am not sure what are the other elements on your webpage but it works ok the way you presented it. See http://wichry.net/page/test.html.

Comment: @kwicher THANKS for your example... I will try it again. at least your example proofs that it is not an issue in the fancybox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works: see Example at http://wichry.net/page/test.html

Code:

```
<a href="images/slimak.png" title="Some text and a hyperlink: &lt;a  href=&quot;http://www.someclient.com?a=1&amp;b=2&quot;&gt;LINKTEXT&lt;/a&gt;">
  <img src="images/slimak.png" alt="alt text of image" /> 
</a>
```